# Truffle install oraclize

Tags: truffle, oracles

I am trying to install oraclize with truffle.

When i run 'truffle install oraclize', I get an error:

```
Could not find suitable configuration file.
```

I am using truffle v4.1.7

Thanks in advance..

Comment: Try 'truffle install oraclize-api' instead!

Comment: Tried this - same error!

Answer (score 1):

Riccardo from Oraclize here.

You can now use our truffle box. 
Start from an empty folder:

```
mkdir ProjectDir

cd ProjectDir

truffle unbox oraclize/truffle-starter
```

The box contains the Oraclize API and some examples.